# Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo el siguiente codigo de Visual Basic en excel para una macro que estoy utilizando el problema es que cuando ejecuto la macro me ejecuta todo correctamente hasta el momento de llegar a la seccion del codigo que dice 'telnet

El telnet se manda a llamar del valor que hay en la celda F10 el cual es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error sucede al ejecutar el AppActivate

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo en VBA

```
Sheets("INICIO").Select

    'telnet
    serial = Range("B4").Text
    telnet = Range("F10").Text
    AppActivate telnet
    SendKeys serial, 400
    Sleep (1200)
    SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
    AppActivate ("Microsoft Excel")
    'AppActivate ("CEK")
    SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"
    Range("B4:C4").Select
    
    Sheets("INICIO").Select
    Range("B4:C4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B5:C5").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B6:C6").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A8:H9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISBLANK(R[-4]C[1]),""Serial Auditado Guardado"",""Introducir Numero de parte y Cantidad"")"
    Range("J5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("B4:C4").Select
    
Else

    Dim Pregunta As Integer
    
   
    Sheets("Concetrado").Select
    Rows("6:6").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    
    Range("K5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[2]C[-2]=R[1]C[-2],0,1)"
    Range("K5").Select
```

Ya probe abriendolo directamente con un `shell` de igual menera mandando por comandos mediante cmd pero cada que se ejecuta la macro con comandos cmd me abre una 2da ventana en ves de utilizar la que ya permanece abierta

Me podrian orientar